# Wordpress Custom post type & taxonomy permalink structure

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have created a CPT with the name 'events'. Below is the code:

```
register_post_type('events', array(
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'author',
            'thumbnail',
        ),
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x('Events', 'plural'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Event', 'singular'),
            'menu_name' => _x('Events', 'admin menu'),
            'name_admin_bar' => _x('Events', 'admin bar'),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'events'),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'capabilities' => array(
            'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow',
        ),
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
    ));
```

Then I created the custom taxonomy 'events-category'. Below is the code:

```
register_taxonomy( 'events-category', 'events', 
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true, 
            'label' => 'Events Category', 
            'query_var' => true,
        )
    );
```

I have added a few 'terms' under the 'events-category' taxonomy like 'test1', 'test2, 'test3.

Now I want to access my posts accordingly:

example.com/events => All the posts related to 'events' CPT.
example.com/events/{post_name} => One particular post under the 'events' CPT.
example.com/events/test1 => All the posts related to the 'events-category' taxonomy.

I have read that I have to modify 'slugs', but not able to make this.

I have tried adding in register_post_type:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'events'),
```

and then add in register_taxonomy:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'events/category' )
```

But nothing is working for me. Please help!